# PHP; Export CSV to output buffer: Loaded File is empty. Why?

Tags: php, header, http-headers, export-to-csv, response-headers

*File resource* - `fopen('php://output')`

*Header list:*

```
Content-Type: application/csv
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.csv"
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Pragma: public
```

*How i download:*

```
ob_clean();
readfile("php://output");
exit;
```

ob_get_contents() before readfile is not empty and data which i write to file too.

But loaded file is empty. Why

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.output

Says:

> `php://output` is a write-only stream that allows you to write to the
>   output buffer mechanism in the same way as **print** and **echo**.

You're trying to read from it, which clearly cannot be done.

It is unclear to me what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. It leads me on some idea.
I just replcae `ob_clean` on `flush` and it is works.

But i cant absolutely recognize. If flush drop the buffer too, even so readfile works good. I mean if buffer droped then , i guess, php://output should be empty and readfile wont work. But it is no so and file is loaded correctly with some data.